# how do i play videos that show text/html decoder plugin-python is missing

Tags: python, video

I have downloaded a few videos but some of them when played with the default movie player show the following error:

> "python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type:text/html decode"
>   "the playback of this movie requires a text/html decoder plugin which is not installed"

while the others don't.

I also tried players like VLC, GNOME MPlayer, KMPlayer but none of them worked.

These videos were being downloaded through the terminal using some python scripts, and the videos showing the above errors keep on looping in the terminal.

Please guide me on installing those plugins.
I'am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thank you in advance.